# Scala: pre-initialize val while extending a class

Tags: scala, initialization, traits

How do I pre-initialize a val and extend a class in Scala?

e.g.:

```
object Start {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        new T()
        new T2()
        //T3?
  }
}

class T extends{val z = 10} with X  with Y
class T2 extends X with Y {val z=10}
//class T3 extends{val z = 10}  ??? Z with X with Y //????

class Z

trait  X {
  val z :Int
}

trait Y { this :X =>
  println("Test: "+z)  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
class T3 extends {val z = 10} with Z with X with Y
```

Scala Language Specification 2.9, 5.1.6:

```
EarlyDefs ::= ‘{’ [EarlyDef {semi EarlyDef}] ‘}’ ‘with’
```

So an early definition **always** has to be followed by a `with`

Comment: Cool - I was about to post a bunch of junk about putting the val in an intermediate class or using DelayedInit. Didn't even know early member definitions were a thing.

Comment: T already does early member definition aka. pre-initialize a value, but it didn't crossed my mind to use `with Clazz`. Scalas praised consistency has a scratch here.

Comment: @StefanK. IMHO not really. It's always `extends` followed by `with`. Unlike Java, `extend` is not for use with classes only, you would also write `class A extends SomeTrait`.

Comment: but why the distinction between `extends` and `with`?

Comment: Honestly, wouldn't astonish me if for historic reasons (i.e. from Java). But I don't know.

Comment: Re why the distinction between `extends` and `with`. In your head, parse it like this: `A extends (B with C with D)`
So intersection type syntax is the answer (note that this is not entirely true: `extends` does **not** allow an arbitrary type, it needs to be a class type).